# Have a same padding in the next line

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML code where when the sentence is too long, it goes to the next line but it wont be in the same line as first sentence.

Is there a way to bring them to same line?

```css
.pad_eff{
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<b class="pad_eff">Deon: </b>sdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsd
```

[image: Current result]

Expected output

[image: Intended result]

Comment: Wrap the entire text with a `span` or something and give it the `padding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your b tag Element and add the padding to the wrapper.

```css
.pad_eff{
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad_eff">
  <b class="">Deon: </b>sdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsd
  </b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose your `b` tag in a `div` and give that the same class and it will do what you want. As there will be a parent `div` which have a padding of `10px` instead of providing padding at just the start of the the text it will provide padding for a multiline text as a container.

```css
.pad_eff{
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad_eff">
<b>Deon: </b>sdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsd
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your whole text element and apply the padding to that element instead of your `b` tag

```css
p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>
<b>Deon: </b>sdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsd
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
p
{
  padding-left:10px;
  text-align:start;
}
</style>



<p>
<b>Deon: </b>sdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsdsdssdfsddddddddddddddddddddb  fsfsdsfsd
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the padd_eff class to the < b > tag, hence why it is padding the left side of that.

Your desired result appears to be having that class applied to the parent class.

So assuming it sits in paragraph

tag:

< p class="padd_eff">< b>Deon</ b> ........</ p>

Comment: Excuse the additional spaces... Can't seem to get formatting working on mobile phone!!